# WebSphere App Server 8.5.5 Setting MQMD.Format from a JMS API

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I am trying to set the MQMD.Format from a java application running on WAS 8.5.5 using native JMS libraries and the Connection Factory and MQ resources managed by WAS:

`TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(xml); 
... 
message.setStringProperty("JMS_IBM_Format", "MQFMT_STRING"); 
...`

The documentation says you need to set JMS_IBM_Format property to MQFMT_STRING, that internally will be mapped against the MQMD.Format field.

In WAS, in the queue configuration, the format property body is "MQ" and the reply is "MQMD".

I have made a lot of tests and combinations of these properties, but no success... In MQ, the format is always set as blank...

Any Idea's/thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood documentation probably. Once you create text message it means that format of your message will be MQFMT_STRING, stored in MQMD.Format or in MQRFH2.Format if MQRFH2 header is present.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rjc0005_.html